# Syntax error on ArrayList declaration

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I've got the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Group {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
}
```

Eclipse (3.0.0) complains about the ArrayList declaration: syntax error on token "(", on both tokens "<", and then on token "=". I'm using java 1.5.0_07.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, regards, Miel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your JDK level to >= 5.0 to enable support for generics.

It's at Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler Compliance Level

Comment: That does the trick, but you need Eclipse version >= 3.1 to get levels > 1.4. For Eclipse 3.5 the default level is set to 1.5. (And that actually is what you mean with 5.0, I guess.)

Comment: Oops; I see you said Eclipse 3.0; did not realize that this option is new to 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Your project is probably set to Java 1.4 target.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've installed 1.5 on your box, but not in Eclipse.  To fix that, go to Window->Preference->Installed JREs, and add your installed JRE.