# ArrayList declaration: syntax error on token "(", on both tokens "<" in android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have google about it online but didn't help and here I am posting my question. I have eclipse version platform version=3.8 which I downloaded from https://developer.android.com to create a android application. Now when I declare a arraylist <> in my program it doesn't recognize it. I read few questions here saying you need to have a version Eclipse version >= 3.1 to be able to increase Java compiler over 1.7. But now my question is when I already have 3.8 why the Java Compiler options are not showing above > 1.7 for me to select. Is android project and eclipse java project a separate thing? I opened eclipse and created this android application project. Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Have you told Eclipse to use a Java 7 JRE and compatibility? Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs is one place to look.

Comment: It only shows 1.7, I read that for me to use <abc> in my android application project as private ArrayList<abc> List1; I need to have JDK level to >= 5.0 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290920/syntax-error-on-arraylist-declaration

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `new`.
Android application should use java 1.5 or 1.6. 
Android is not supporting 1.7.`ArrayList<object> abcd= new ArrayList<object>();`

And if you want to use java 1.7 in Java application project. Java 1.7 should be installed in your PC.

my guess would be that while you run eclipse itself with jdk 1.6, it's actually configured with a different default jre. see window->preferences->java->Installed JREs and make sure that the checked JRE is 1.6.

if the default JRE is indeed 1.6, chances are that it's a project specific setting. see that the project is configured to use the right jre.

Comment: So Android cannot support > 1.7? and that means I cannot use private ArrayList<abc> List1; in android application project? Thanks for the response.

Comment: `ArrayList<abc> abc= ArrayList<abc>();` is correct syntax and we can use it. Who said we can't use?

Comment: I am unable to use private ArrayList<abc> List1; in Android project and it says <abc> cannot be recognized. I am using ADT Build 21.1.0 and Eclipse 3.8 and JDK compiler for the Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler Compliance Level only shows until 1.7 to select. Here is what I am following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290920/syntax-error-on-arraylist-declaration

Comment: Yes android wont support 1.7

Comment: I didn't say that you can't use

Comment: You can use 1.7 for other Java projects other than android

Comment: See this link. it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea

Comment: I added little more with my answer.

Comment: Well thats exactly the issue is, <abc> cannot be resolved if I use above in android application as it is using JDK 1.6 or so. Article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290920/syntax-error-on-arraylist-declaration says I need to have Eclipse > 3.1 but i already have Eclipse 3.8 and Android developer tool version shows V21.0

Comment: You didn't add new with the syntax

Comment: Can I declare a arraylist like this ?  private ArrayList <abc> MyArrayList; in android project? I am getting an error abc cannot be resolved. If I try above statement from comment above I get error: object cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Tell me ,What is abc here.? It should be class name. (It should be an Object type)